# Magento2 Seller Sub Domain Configuration

Tags: magento2, htaccess, apache2, subdomain

We are using multivendor marketplace in magento2. Now i we have login for seller as http://mystore.com/marketplace/vendor/login , I want to make it as seller.mystore.com that means when ever seller.mystore.com opened by any one it will show the vendor login page.

How can i configure my subdomain here.?

I am using apache2. Is there any way by using htaccess with out redirect? I just needs to load /marketplace/vendor/login form when user enters seller.mystore.com